"Test suite failed to run Cannot find module" getting issue with absolute path in Angular 14 test suite
I have just upgraded my Angular project from Angular 13 to Angular 14, Functionality wise everything is working fine but whenever I tried to run the test suite I am getting below error

Test suite failed to run
   Cannot find module 'src/app/constants/alert' from 'src/app/review-details/review-details.component.spec.ts'

    >  8 | import { ALERT_ID } from 'src/app/constants/alert';

Earlier in Angular 13 it was working properly with absolute path.
I was try with relative path, but my project is to much huge and so many files needs to modify with relative path.
here is my jest.config.js file
module.exports = {
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@core/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/app/core/$1'
  },
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts'],
  coverageReporters: ['html', 'lcov', 'text-summary'],
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageDirectory: '<rootDir>/coverage/program-catalog-ui',
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/', '<rootDir>/dist/', '<rootDir>/projects/']
};

Below are the dependencies from package.json file
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "0.1402.13",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "14.2.13",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "14.2.13",
    "@angular/animations": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "14.3.0",
    "@briebug/jest-schematic": "3.1.0",
    "@jest/types": "28.0.0",
    "@ncstate/sat-popover": "4.0.0",
    "@ngneat/svg-icon": "3.2.0",
    "@types/mixpanel": "2.14.3",
    "ag-grid-angular": "24.0.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "24.0.0",
    "chart.js": "3.9.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "mixpanel": "0.14.0",
    "mixpanel-browser": "2.45.0",
    "nanoid": "3.1.20",
    "ng-packagr": "18.0.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "1.4.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "2.2.0",
    "rxjs": "6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/jest": "14.1.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "14.2.13",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "14.4.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "14.4.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "14.4.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "14.4.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "14.4.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "14.2.7",
    "@angular/cli": "14.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "14.3.0",
    "@commitlint/cli": "8.3.5",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "8.3.4",
    "@schematics/angular": "14.2.13",
    "@types/jest": "26.0.23",
    "@types/mixpanel-browser": "2.38.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.11.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "commitiquette": "1.0.4",
    "commitizen": "4.1.2",
    "eslint": "^8.28.0",
    "fs-extra": "9.0.1",
    "husky": "4.2.5",
    "jest": "28.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "10.2.9",
    "prettier": "2.0.5",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "stylelint": "13.6.0",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "3.0.0",
    "stylelint-order": "4.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.4",
    "validate-branch-name": "1.0.6"
  },

I also tried below steps many times

jest --clearCache
rmdir /s /q node_modules
del package-lock.json
npm install

Thanks in advance

After adding
moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', __dirname]
into jest.config.js file atlest test suits are running
But still giving error for nanoid
`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
  2 | import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  3 | import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
> 4 | import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';`

